# What is the use of this Postgres file in /var/lib/pgsql/db_log_archive?

Tags: database, postgresql, server, centos, centos7

I'm trying my level best to reduce server space by deleting the unnecessary file and I come across with this file with huge space after running this command

```
[root$]# du -a / 2>/dev/null | sort -n -r | head -n 5

98926364        /
64453368        /var
63947356        /var/lib
63816012        /var/lib/pgsql
47322196        /var/lib/pgsql/db_log_archive
```

Does anyone know the importance of this file **/var/lib/pgsql/db_log_archive** in my **centos 7 server** ? I want to delete this

Comment: I'm betting that that is a directory, not a file.  What is inside it?

Comment: @jjanes, inside this folder, you will find many files with an unknown format like this 
`000000020000001D0000009E                  000000020000002300000061
000000020000001D0000009F                  000000020000002300000062
000000020000001D000000A0                  000000020000002300000063
000000020000001D000000A2                  000000020000002300000065
000000020000001D000000A2.00000020.backup  000000020000002300000066`

Comment: This looks like WAL segments from the database. Please check your postgresql.conf file as I already mentionned.

Comment: Exactly, I got this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your WAL archive.  I am not aware of CentOS 7 doing this automatically (but I've never used 7).  Someone has probably gone out of their way to create this directory and then configure `archive_command` (from `postgresql.conf`) to copy WAL to it.

If the person who set up your database is still around, you should ask them what their intentions were.

These could be part of a valid backup strategy.  Or they could be part of an invalid backup strategy.  Or they could be left over from a no-longer-used backup strategy.  You would have to describe what your current backup system is for anyone to know.

Comment: yes, I have passed through the configuration file and found this

Comment: # - Archiving -

`archive_mode = on               # allows archiving to be done
                                # (change requires restart)
archive_command = 'test ! -f /var/lib/pgsql/db_log_archive/%f && cp %p /var/lib/pgsql/db_log_archive/%f'                # command to use to archive a logfile segment
                                # placeholders: %p = path of file to archive`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standard directory created by PostgreSQL on CentOS.

Check your postgresql.conf for any reference for this name if it is directly used by PostgreSQL (maybe for backing up WAL).